# Why is my protected loop erroring?

Tags: python, while-loop

I have this script

```
for line in file:
    while line[i] == " ":
        if i == len(line):
            break
        i += 1
    if i == len(line):
        pass
    while not line[i] == " ":
        if i == len(line):
            break
        obj += line[i]
        i += 1
    print obj
```

As of now, `file` equals `["clear", "exit"]` and `i` equals `0`.

When I run this script, it errors like this

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ubuntu/workspace/lib/source.py", line 8, in <module>
    while not line[i] == " ":
IndexError: string index out of range
```

I'm pretty sure my loop is protected right, and it should break before this happens. If this the case, then why is it happening?

Comment: `i` is not defined in your code snippet. Please update a code to demonstrate [MCVE].

Comment: `i` is out of range when evaluating the condition.  `pass` probably doesn't do what you think it does.

Comment: Edited to include value of i

Comment: Are you trying to understand the code you posted, or are you just looking for `stripped_line = line.strip()`?  (See the [`str.strip` docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.strip), along with `lstrip` and `rstrip` on that same page.)

Comment: @KevinJ.Chase I'm trying to fix my code, as it is getting an IndexError, and print the obj.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> my loop is protected

No it isn't. The condition on the `while` has to be evaluated first before reaching the body of the loop where the *protection* `if` condition is.

To be sure `i` does not exceed the length of the list, move the condition on the `if` and make it the first condition on the `while`:

```
while i < len(line) and not line[i] == " ":
    obj += line[i]
    i += 1
```

---

Otherwise you could move the `if` block after the update of `i` so the condition is evaluated before that of the next iteration of `while`:

```
while not line[i] == " ":
    obj += line[i]
    i += 1
    if i == len(line):
        break
```

Comment: `obj` is never printed, fix?

Comment: @bjskistad You can plug that part into your main code.

Comment: I did, and it's printing two blank values.

Comment: @bjskistad I changed the condition on the while. Check update

Comment: Now giving me IndexError

Comment: I updated, you could also try the second approach instead

Answer (score 1):

Your loop is not "safe", "break" only breaks **inner** loop, thus once i==len(line) it goes out of first while, stays in the main for and you try to read out line[i] in "while not line[i] == """ line, which causes you to index outside "line" (since the condition is checked before entering the loop).

```
for line in file:
    while line[i] == " ":
        if i == len(line):   
            break # THIS executes, thus i == len(line)
        i += 1
    if i == len(line): # this is true, thus nothing happens, pass is no-op
        pass
    while not line[i] == " ": # this executes, and fails since i == len(line)
        if i == len(line):
            break
        obj += line[i]
        i += 1
    print obj
```

Comment: What do you mean `pass` is no-op? It would have to operate if the condition is true.

Comment: I mean that "pass" does nothing, this is literaly no-op in python, it does not affect the execution in any sense. Maybe you meant "continue"?